# WebRTC - What server architecture for Few To Many audio broadcasting with minimal latency

Tags: android, ios, audio, webrtc, live-streaming

I need to build an architecture to broadcast live an audio conference. In details, this means :
 - 2 to 5 people (let's call them broadcasters) talk with each other audio only, in Web, iOS or Android 
 - Server gets the streams, mux it, and broadcast it to Web, iOS or Android
 - Server records the muxed stream

This is live broadcasting, where I need minimal latency from broadcasters to listeners (max 1 second), and even shorter between broadcasters so they can have a normal discussion.

I think using webRTC might be the best solution for the audio conference part (but I may be wrong...)

**QUESTION :**
What server should I use for muxing and broadcasting, insuring minimum latency?

The main things I have looked into :
 - Kurento, but the dev community does not seem to big, so I am afraid I will be a bit alone when it comes to debugging
 - Asterisk/FreeSwitch SIP server : looks like way too much for my use case. No idea what this gives in terms of latency.

Comment: Have you looked into the [Janus-Gateway](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway)?

Comment: Even I am into the same kind of project...Kurento's docs are pretty outdated and very less demos are provided. I tried out Jitsi, but too much overhead.
Do tell me about any progress of yours...

Comment: Moreover only handling 2-5 systems with only Audio, can be easily done without any server architecture, You should try http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/...This will do your job.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent, I heard of it and tried to check it out, but I can't really say from the docs what it is for. Do you think that would work?  And the docs are really bad...

Comment: @HardeepMehta, I'll keep you udpated. The reason I need a server is for broadcasting to other listeners. If I do that serverless, it will be a huge bandwidth burden for my users

Comment: @Ness the Kurento community is growing, and quite alive at the moment. You can check the group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kurento), and give it a try.